# why it is called operator overloading and not method overloading since we are overloading methods in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example whenever we overload some of the operators in python like                                   str, mul, add,etc(obviously with underscores with them) but i think these are     methods,so shouldn't it be called as method overloading instead?correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Those aren't operators.

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading means having an "operator" (like `*` or `+`) doing different things depending on context.

Method overloading means having multiple methods of the same name in the same class that are differentiated by their parameter signature.

In your Python example, operator overloading is implemented by providing specially named methods (which themselves are not overloaded, as long as you have just one of them per class for each name).

Comment: yea i know that but your answer doesn't answers my question.

Comment: Why not? How many `__add__` methods do you have on your class? If just one, there is no overloading.

Comment: consider if i am writing another __add__ method to overload pre-defined __add__ method.now my question is-this is known as operator overloading(overloading of add method) shouldn't it be called as method overloading instead?

Comment: is the pre-defined add method in the same class? Having methods of the same name in different class is not overloading.  And even if you use overloaded methods to implement operator overloading, the important thing is that you have achieved operator overloading (does not matter much how you did that, at least not to the user of the overloaded operator).

Comment: It's like saying shouldn't it be called "OOP" instead of "operator overloading" because I am using OOP (classes, methods) to implement it.